# Replace punctuation by one space

Tags: perl, shell, unix

I used this command to list all punctuations in text

```
 perl -CSD -nE '$seen{$1}++ while /(\pP)/g; END { say "$_ $seen{$_}" for keys %seen }' file.txt
```

how to replaced it then with one space ''

for example

```
Said Mr. Nkumbula last night: "We want to discuss what to do
if the British Government gives in to Sir Roy and the talks fall
through. There are bound to be demonstrations."
```

will become

```
Said Mr  Nkumbula last night   We want to discuss what to do
if the British Government gives in to Sir Roy and the talks fall
through  There are bound to be demonstrations
```

Comment: "Pronunciations" doesn't make sense. Did you mean punctuation characters? Can you give us a small sample input and the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does

```
  perl -pe 's/\pP/ /g' file.txt
```

do what you expect? Alternative: list the characters you don't want:

```
  sed -e 's/[.":;]/ /g' file.txt
```

Comment: It does exactly what you want here. Since \pP  involves unicode, maybe it's a locale problem. See the alternative.